# Kubernetes deployment.yaml for django+gunicorn+nginx

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have created docker images using docker-compose.yml as below

```
version: '2'

services:

  djangoapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/sig_app
      - static_volume:/sig_app
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/sig_app
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

I have used docker-compose build and docker-compose up. The three images are created as below

1. kubernetes_djangoapp
2. docker.io/python
3. docker.io/nginx

I want to deploy the application into kubernetes using YAML file.
I am new to kubernetes.
Django application is running with port 8000
and Nginx with port 80

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: django-nginx
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: nginx-host
        hostPath:
          path: /config/nginx/conf.d 
      containers:
      - name: djangoapp
        image: kubernetes_djangoapp
        volumeMounts:
        - name: django-nginx
          mountPath: /sig_app
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.13
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: django-nginx
          mountPath: /sig_app
        - name: nginx-host
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Note that you will have to modify some things to make it custom yours. I am missing where the image is. You should upload it to docker hub, or any registry of your choice.

About the volumes, here both containers share a non-persistent volume (django-nginx), which maps `/sig_app` directory in each container with each other. And another one that shares the container nginx (etc/nginx/conf.d) with your host (/config/nginx/conf.d), to pass the config file. A better way would be to use a ConfigMap. Check on that.

So, yeah, set the image for django and let me know if it doesn't work, and we will see whats failing.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you @suren. I am getting 'Back-off restarting failed container' error. In log its showing Error: can't chdir to 'aggregator'

Comment: that's a error thrown by your app. What does `kubectl describe pod` says? And what changes did you do?

Comment: I have changed the URL of a public image from docker hub.
pod saying
`pulling image "si*******or/nginx"
Created container
Started container
Successfully pulled image "si*******or/nginx"
pulling image "sigmaaggregator/sigma"
Created container
Started container
Successfully pulled image "si*******or/sigma"
Back-off restarting failed container`

Comment: ok. so that usually happens when there are no processes running within the container. So the container gets terminated and re-deployed (because there is a deployment behind). Do you start your container usually with a command or it is done in the Dockerfile (with a CMD or ENTRYPOINT)?

Comment: It is done in Dockerfile with CMD ["gunicorn", "--chdir", "aggregator", "--bind", ":8000", "aggre.wsgi:application"]

Comment: Ok. So that was the error you first mentioned. You need to fix that part. Not sure how, because Im not familiar with gunicorn. But once that fixed, k8s part should work.

Comment: Hi @suren
I have resolved the issue but how to expose the service outside with load balancer and the service code as below
`# Backend Service
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: admin-api-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer`
Its not working

Comment: If you are running Kubernetes on bare metal, it won't work. Where are you running it?

Comment: I am running it in the kubernetes dashboard.

Comment: I mean any cloud? Google, Amazon, ...? or you made it with VMs? Or physical machines...

Comment: I am using AWS(Amazon)

Comment: In AWS it should work. can you paste your deployment.yaml and service.yaml files?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Kompose](https://kompose.io/). It will allow you to simply run the command

```
kompose up
```

to immediately deploy your docker-compose configuration to your cluster.

If you want to create a `.yaml` from your docker-compose file first to inspect and edit, you can run

```
kompose convert
```